# Running first React-Native app fails

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to set up my first React-Native app. and getting the attached error.

Following the official guide:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/getting-started.html for Mac + iOS

All installations were fine but when running

`Guydu@Guys-MacBook-Pro AwesomeProject $ react-native run-ios`

I get the following error:

```
Found Xcode project AwesomeProject.xcodeproj
Launching iPhone 6 (8.4)...
Building using "xcodebuild -project AwesomeProject.xcodeproj -scheme AwesomeProject -destination id=5A6EAE50-8D20-414B-A882-5B4560596EF7 -derivedDataPath build"
User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build

=== BUILD TARGET RCTGeolocation OF PROJECT RCTGeolocation WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Write auxiliary files
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build
write-file /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/RCTGeolocation-own-target-headers.hmap
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64
write-file /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTGeolocation.LinkFileList
write-file /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/RCTGeolocation-all-target-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/RCTGeolocation-project-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/RCTGeolocation-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/RCTGeolocation.hmap
write-file /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/RCTGeolocation-generated-files.hmap

CompileC /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTLocationObserver.o RCTLocationObserver.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Geolocation
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/Guydu/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/Guydu/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=115 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wshadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -iquote /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/RCTGeolocation-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/RCTGeolocation-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/RCTGeolocation-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/RCTGeolocation-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I../../React -I../../React/Base -I../../React/CSSLayout -I../../React/Executors -I../../React/Modules -I../../React/Profiler -I../../React/Views -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/DerivedSources -Werror -Wall -F/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTLocationObserver.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTLocationObserver.dia -c /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Geolocation/RCTLocationObserver.m -o /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTGeolocation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTGeolocation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTLocationObserver.o

=== BUILD TARGET RCTSettings OF PROJECT RCTSettings WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

CompileC /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTSettings.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTSettings.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTSettingsManager.o RCTSettingsManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/Guydu/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/Guydu/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=115 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wshadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -iquote /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTSettings.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTSettings.build/RCTSettings-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTSettings.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTSettings.build/RCTSettings-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTSettings.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTSettings.build/RCTSettings-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTSettings.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTSettings.build/RCTSettings-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I../../React -I../../React/Base -I../../React/CSSLayout -I../../React/Executors -I../../React/Modules -I../../React/Profiler -I../../React/Views -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTSettings.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTSettings.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTSettings.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTSettings.build/DerivedSources -Werror -Wall -F/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTSettings.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTSettings.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTSettingsManager.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTSettings.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTSettings.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTSettingsManager.dia -c /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings/RCTSettingsManager.m -o /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTSettings.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTSettings.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTSettingsManager.o
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings/RCTSettingsManager.m:10:
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings/RCTSettingsManager.h:12:
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:222:14: error: expected '>'
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeMethod>> *)methodsToExport;
             ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:222:14: error: expected ')'
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:222:3: note: to match this '('
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeMethod>> *)methodsToExport;
  ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:222:1: error: interface type 'NSArray' cannot be returned by value; did you
      forget * in 'NSArray'?
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeMethod>> *)methodsToExport;
^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:231:26: error: expected '>'
- (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)constantsToExport;
                         ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:231:27: error: expected ')'
- (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)constantsToExport;
                          ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:231:3: note: to match this '('
- (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)constantsToExport;
  ^
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings/RCTSettingsManager.m:12:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:12:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:10:
../../React/Base/RCTJavaScriptLoader.h:16:18: error: too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
NS_ENUM(NSInteger) {
                 ^
In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings/RCTSettingsManager.h:10:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:268:9: note: 
      macro 'NS_ENUM' defined here
#define NS_ENUM(_type, _name) CF_ENUM(_type, _name)
        ^
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings/RCTSettingsManager.m:12:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:12:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:10:
../../React/Base/RCTJavaScriptLoader.h:16:1: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
      [-Werror,-Wimplicit-int]
NS_ENUM(NSInteger) {
^
../../React/Base/RCTJavaScriptLoader.h:16:8: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
NS_ENUM(NSInteger) {
       ^
       ;
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings/RCTSettingsManager.m:12:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:12:
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:50:14: error: expected '>'
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge;
             ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:50:14: error: expected ')'
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:50:3: note: to match this '('
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge;
  ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:50:1: error: interface type 'NSArray' cannot be returned by value; did you
      forget * in 'NSArray'?
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge;
^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:64:12: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'Class'
- (NSArray<Class> *)whitelistedModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge;
           ^
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings/RCTSettingsManager.m:12:
../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:59:19: error: expected '>'
typedef NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *(^RCTBridgeModuleProviderBlock)(void);
                  ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:59:19: error: expected identifier or '('
../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:94:36: error: expected a type
                   moduleProvider:(RCTBridgeModuleProviderBlock)block
                                   ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:143:47: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'Class'
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSArray<Class> *moduleClasses;
                                              ^
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings/RCTSettingsManager.m:13:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTConvert.h:18:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTLog.h:12:
../../React/Base/RCTAssert.h:138:76: error: expected '>'
RCT_EXTERN NSString *RCTFormatError(NSString *message, NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *> *stacktrace...
                                                                           ^
../../React/Base/RCTAssert.h:138:76: error: interface type 'NSArray' cannot be passed by value; did you forget * in
      'NSArray'?
RCT_EXTERN NSString *RCTFormatError(NSString *message, NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *> *stacktrace...
                                                                           ^
                                                       *
../../React/Base/RCTAssert.h:138:76: error: expected ')'
../../React/Base/RCTAssert.h:138:36: note: to match this '('
RCT_EXTERN NSString *RCTFormatError(NSString *message, NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *> *stacktrace...
                                   ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.

=== BUILD TARGET RCTImage OF PROJECT RCTImage WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

=== BUILD TARGET RCTActionSheet OF PROJECT RCTActionSheet WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies

CompileC /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTActionSheet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTActionSheet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTActionSheetManager.o RCTActionSheetManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/Guydu/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/Guydu/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=115 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wshadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -iquote /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTActionSheet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTActionSheet.build/RCTActionSheet-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTActionSheet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTActionSheet.build/RCTActionSheet-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTActionSheet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTActionSheet.build/RCTActionSheet-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTActionSheet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTActionSheet.build/RCTActionSheet-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I../../React -I../../React/Base -I../../React/CSSLayout -I../../React/Executors -I../../React/Modules -I../../React/Profiler -I../../React/Views -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTActionSheet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTActionSheet.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTActionSheet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTActionSheet.build/DerivedSources -Wextra -Wall -F/Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTActionSheet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTActionSheet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTActionSheetManager.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTActionSheet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTActionSheet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTActionSheetManager.dia -c /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.m -o /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTActionSheet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTActionSheet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTActionSheetManager.o
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.m:10:
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.h:12:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:12:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:10:
../../React/Base/RCTJavaScriptLoader.h:16:18: error: too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
NS_ENUM(NSInteger) {
                 ^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.h:10:
In module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:268:9: note: 
      macro 'NS_ENUM' defined here
#define NS_ENUM(_type, _name) CF_ENUM(_type, _name)
        ^
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.m:10:
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.h:12:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:12:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:10:
../../React/Base/RCTJavaScriptLoader.h:16:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
NS_ENUM(NSInteger) {
^
../../React/Base/RCTJavaScriptLoader.h:16:8: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
NS_ENUM(NSInteger) {
       ^
       ;
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.m:10:
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.h:12:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:12:
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:50:14: error: expected '>'
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge;
             ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:50:14: error: expected ')'
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:50:3: note: to match this '('
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge;
  ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:50:1: error: interface type 'NSArray' cannot be returned by value; did you
      forget * in 'NSArray'?
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge;
^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h:64:12: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'Class'
- (NSArray<Class> *)whitelistedModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge;
           ^
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.m:10:
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.h:12:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:13:
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:222:14: error: expected '>'
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeMethod>> *)methodsToExport;
             ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:222:14: error: expected ')'
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:222:3: note: to match this '('
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeMethod>> *)methodsToExport;
  ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:222:1: error: interface type 'NSArray' cannot be returned by value; did you
      forget * in 'NSArray'?
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeMethod>> *)methodsToExport;
^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:231:26: error: expected '>'
- (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)constantsToExport;
                         ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:231:27: error: expected ')'
- (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)constantsToExport;
                          ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:231:3: note: to match this '('
- (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)constantsToExport;
  ^
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.m:10:
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.h:12:
../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:59:19: error: expected '>'
typedef NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *(^RCTBridgeModuleProviderBlock)(void);
                  ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:59:19: error: expected identifier or '('
../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:94:36: error: expected a type
                   moduleProvider:(RCTBridgeModuleProviderBlock)block
                                   ^
../../React/Base/RCTBridge.h:143:47: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'Class'
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSArray<Class> *moduleClasses;
                                              ^
In file included from /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.m:12:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTConvert.h:18:
In file included from ../../React/Base/RCTLog.h:12:
../../React/Base/RCTAssert.h:138:76: error: expected '>'
RCT_EXTERN NSString *RCTFormatError(NSString *message, NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *> *stacktrace...

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTSettings.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTSettings.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTSettingsManager.o RCTSettingsManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/Guydu/Apps/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTActionSheet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTActionSheet.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTActionSheetManager.o RCTActionSheetManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app
No devices are booted.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

any ideas what's the issue in here? thanks!

Comment: check if nothing is running on port 8081 lsof -n -i4TCP:8081  If something is running just kill it

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded OS, deleted and re-installed Xcode - it solved it and now it works